# MapBox, Kotlin. draw a path as user location changes

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

Im trying to create a running app with MapBox, in Kotlin. I managed to get track live location working, I know how to set a marker on starting point. But I don't know how to draw the path the user walked, or ran so I can show it when the user press stop. And also, get the distance que walked, or ran.

Don't know if this is possible. I have managed to get directions from point A to B, but this is different.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

got it working.with create line layer documentation and listen to location updates, just creating a mutable list of Point so at the end of the run I just pass the list to the create line layer and it draws the path